# Multiple TextField in Wicket Form

Tags: java, wicket

I have a bean, which I attached to the form using Model and it works fine. Also I have a field in bean like `Map<String, javax.mail.Address>`. How can I bind this field with form by model considering that every map entry should be like `Label: TextField`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
ListView<String> textAreasListView = new ListView<String>("someid", bean.map.keySet()) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<String> itemLang) {
        itemLang.add(new Label("label", itemLang.getModelObject()));
        Model<String> textModel = new Model<String>() {

            @Override
            public String getObject() {
                return bean.map.get(itemLang.getModelObject()).toString;
            }

            @Override
            public void setObject(String object) {
                bean.map.put(itemLang.getModelObject(), new Address(object));
            }
        };
        itemLang.add(new TextField<String>("email", textModel));
    }
};
```

and add this to your form.

A custom converter for Address & String would be an additional improvement.

Comment: I'm glad :-); don't forget to accept (and optionally upvote) the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could bind it in such a way:

```
TextField<Address> textField = new TextField<Address>("address",
        beanModel.<Address> bind("addressMap[addressKey]"), Address.class) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <C> IConverter<C> getConverter(Class<C> type) {
        if (Address.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (IConverter<C>) new AddressConverter();
        } else {
            return super.getConverter(type);
        }
    }
};
form.add(textField);
```

Here "addressMap" is name of the map field, "addressKey" is the key of the address value in the map.

The listing for AddressConverter class:

```
public class AddressConverter implements IConverter<Address> {

    public Address convertToObject(String string, Locale locale) {
        try {
            return new InternetAddress(string);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String convertToString(Address address, Locale locale) {
        return address.toString();
    }
}
```

Of course, converter for Address class may be attached globally with the ConverterLocator. Just add the following method to your Application class:

```
@Override
protected IConverterLocator newConverterLocator() {
    ConverterLocator locator = new ConverterLocator();
    locator.set(Address.class, new AddressConverter());
    return locator;
}
```

And then you don't need to override getConverter() method on the all text fields.